# Can Video capture in windows media foundation used for screen capturing?

Tags: c++, windows, ms-media-foundation, screen-capture

can desktop screen be captured using [Video capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940439(v=vs.85).aspx) in windows media foundation.
After reading windows developer guide, it seems it is used for capturing video from devices such camera or other external devices.
If yes, is it hardware accelerated API or software base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For desktop screen capture you should look at the output duplication feature implemented through [IDXGIOutputDuplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404611(v=vs.85).aspx). What you do is obtain the DXGI object for the video adapter you need, enumerate the outputs to find the needed one (or all if you do a simultaneous capture from multiple screens) and duplicate it through a call to [IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404600(v=vs.85).aspx). The duplication gives you access to the GPU video surface that can be mapped to CPU readable memory - so yes it is accelerated.

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DXGIDesktopDuplication) is a complete sample from Microsoft on this matter.

Comment: Thanks @Rudolfs, Yes i know about DXGI. is it DXGI uses [Video capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940439(v=vs.85).aspx) from media foundation? or how this class is related to DXGI?  and DXGI is not supported in windows 7.

Comment: @anurudh - this is in no way related with Video capture. DXGI works through Direct3D not Media Foundation. And yes, it is not supported on Windows 7 - you have to use older methods for Windows 7.

Comment: ok. I am still waiting for answer that, can video capture be used screen capturing?

Comment: @anurudh - there is no definite answer. I you enumerate the sources for video capture of course there will be nothing that will provide you the contents of the screen, however anyone can do a custom source that wraps duplication, GDI or whatever.

Comment: Thanks @Rudolf. I ll try to deep down it, and try to answer here with more evidences.

Comment: @anurudh what exactly do you want to prove?

Comment: I am not getting second part of your comment " however anyone can ....... ". AIK video capture do enumeration for video devices such as camera etc.... my question is can be do same for desktop device also.

Comment: @anurudh You can create a dll that installs a source filter which is of video capture type and then it will be enumerated as well. A source filter is not necessarily a hardware component.

Comment: Thanks @RudolfsBundulis. I ll try as you suggested.  Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you need resolve very specific task and I think that there is a solution which is very close to your needs. On site "CodeProject" there is article "CaptureManager SDK". It includes interesting example code for streaming desktop screen and output speaker buffer by Media Foundation. It can stream to web browser by MP4 format. I think you can find it interesting.